# Why does getCount in adapter is being called so many times?

Tags: android, listview, listadapter

I have a custom list and it takes few minutes to show-up. When I was trying to check where the problem is, I saw that even when I have only 1 item in the list, the method getCount() is being called 5 times, getVIew() is being called once, an then getCount() is being called to more time.
Overall getCount() is being called 7 times. Does that makes sense?

Thank you!

Comment: PLease provide code sample!

Comment: Show the code. And I rather doubt getCount() make your list crawl

Comment: were you scrolling? provide more data

Comment: Scrolling is fine. I mean it's takes time for the list view to appear on screen. I will attach the code soon I hope. Tnx

Comment: Still unsolved... I am help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can see [here](http://grepcode.com/search/usages?type=method&id=repository.grepcode.com%24java%24ext@com.google.android%24android@4.1.1_r1@android%24widget@Adapter@getCount%28%29&k=u) the different internal calls to the `Adapter.getCount()` method.

But you must keep in mind that you have no control on how this method is gonna be called.

It can be called multiple times and that's why you have to keep it as fast as possible.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understood the "keep it as fast as possible" part- this method only returns the array size right?

Comment: Sure. But you can override it as you like. The idea is to make sure you don't do any costly computation in it, since it is likely to be called many times and in UI thread.

Comment: I didn't override it. all I do is return the array size. So I guess that's mean that the time that takes the listView to appear has got nothing to do with the getCount() that being called many times?

Comment: Probably not...You could use DDMS profiling tools to see what actually consumes CPU

Answer (score 2):

`getCount()` is called too many times because `App-USER` can `update its list` ( can add data in its storage ) anytime and thats why we return , `(storage).size()` (total number of elements).

Answer (score 0):

Adapter `getCount()` method  will be called in following cases.

1) when setting the adapter to List view/ Grid View.

2) when we call `notifyDataSetChanged`  on Adapter.

So, check in your code, you might be doing the above cases more time or recursively..

Answer (score 0):

You should have a search button that updates the adapter when searching. That method get called drawing the view multiple times, if inside that method you have a `setAdapter`, then, `getCount` will be called many times, and will ended up returning 0 and you view will not be filled.